# Map vector of vectors to vector of hashes in Clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have a vector of points in 2D space such as:

```
[[0 0] [1 1] [2 2]]
```

And need to compute the distance between some point and each point in the vector to determine which point in the vector is closest to the point I'm querying. I need to know both the distance and the closest point, so I want a vector of hashes like this:

```
[{:point [0 0] :dist 2.7} {:point [1 1] :dist 3.5} {:point [2 2] :dist 4.3}]
```

How can I transform the former into the latter? I tried something like this:

```
(defn closest-point [point all-points]
    (map #({:point % :dist (distance point %)}) all-points))
```

But I get an error:

```
(user=> ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentArrayMap  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more readable if you use a `for` comprehension instead of a `map`. Also, to actually select the nearest point, you can just use `min-key`:

```
(defn closest-point [point all-points]
  (apply min-key :dist
         (for [p all-points]
           {:point p :dist (distance point p)})))
```

Answer (score 9):

`#({...})` expands into `(fn [] ({....}))` which tries to call the map without any arguments.

Try this:

```
(defn closest-point [point all-points]
    (map (fn [p] {:point p :dist (distance point p)}) all-points))
```

or

```
(defn closest-point [point all-points]
    (map #(hash-map :point % :dist (distance point %)) all-points))
```

or

```
(defn dist-info
  [point p]
  {:point p :dist (distance point p)})

(defn closest-point [point all-points]
    (map #(dist-info point %) all-points))
```

Comment: Joost, thanks. I had a copy and paste error which omitted the #() around my hash, which I fixed in the question now. Your second solution works perfectly! If you remove the opening paragraph and the first example (which doesn't work), I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

What about fixing it without removing anything from your code and just adding a single word : `identity`

```
(defn closest-point [point all-points]
    (map #(identity {:point % :dist (distance point %)}) all-points))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn closest-point [point all-points]
  (map #(hash-map :point % :dist (distance point %) ) all-points)
```

Result:-

```
({:point [0 0], :dist 2.7} {:point [1 1], :dist 3.5} {:point [2 2], :dist 4})
```