# Clojure - get data inside vector of vectors

Tags: clojure, lighttable

I have a vector of vectors that contains some strings and ints:

```
(def data [
["a" "title" "b" 1]
["c" "title" "d" 1]
["e" "title" "f" 2]
["g" "title" "h" 1]
])
```

I'm trying to iterate through the vector and return(?) any rows that contain a certain string e.g. "a". I tried implementing things like this:

```
(defn get-row [data]
  (for [d [data]
        :when (= (get-in d[0]) "a")] d
  ))
```

I'm quite new to Clojure, but I believe this is saying: For every element (vector) in 'data', if that vector contains "a", return it?

I know get-in needs 2 parameters, that part is where I'm unsure of what to do.

I have looked at answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997620/clojure-rearrangement-and-mapping-of-vector-of-vectors) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471642/map-vector-of-vectors-to-vector-of-hashes-in-clojure) but I don't really understand how they work. From what I can gather they're converting the vector to a map and doing the operations on that instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(filter #(some #{"a"} %) data)
```

It's a bit strange seeing the set `#{"a"}` but it works as a predicate function for [`some`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some). Adding more entries to the set would be like a logical OR for it, i.e.

```
(filter #(some #{"a" "c"} %) data)
=> (["a" "title" "b" 1] ["c" "title" "d" 1])
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but I'm not really sure how? Am I correct in thinking what you're doing is filtering all of the elements (%) in data against the set containing just "a"?

Comment: {**filter** down `data` by { is there **some** element recognized by {**set** "a" }? } }

Comment: In Clojure, apart from being a data structure, a set is also a function. Applying the function #{"a" "b"} to a value will return that value if it is either "a" or "b" otherwise it will return nil. `some` applies a function to every value in a sequence in turn until it finds one that returns a truthy value. `filter` goes through each element in a sequence and only keeps the ones that return a truthy value to the function you give it. I recommend you play around with all 3 functions in a REPL http://www.tryclj.com/

Answer (score 1):

ok you have error in your code

```
(defn get-row [data]
  (for [d [data]
        :when (= (get-in d[0]) "a")] d
  ))
```

the error is here: 
`(for [d [data] ...`
to traverse all the elements you shouldn't enclose `data` in brackets, because this syntax is for creating vectors. Here you are trying to traverse a vector of one element. that is how it look like for clojure:

```
    (for [d [[["a" "title" "b" 1]
              ["c" "title" "d" 1]
              ["e" "title" "f" 2]
              ["g" "title" "h" 1]]] ...
```

so, correct variant is:

```
(defn get-row [data]
  (for [d data
        :when (= "a" (get-in d [0]))]
    d))
```

then, you could use clojure' destructuring for that:

```
(defn get-row [data]
  (for [[f & _ :as d] data
        :when (= f "a")]
    d))
```

but more clojuric way is to use higher order functions:

```
(defn get-row [data]
  (filter #(= (first %) "a") data))
```

that is about your code. But corretc variant is in other guys' answers, because here you are checking just first item.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I see where I'm going wrong now.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn get-row [data]
  (for [d data ; <-- fix: [data] would result 
               ; in one iteration with d bound to data
        :when (= (get-in d[0]) "a")]
    d))
```

Observe that your algorithm returns rows where the first column is "a". This can e. g. be solved using `some` with a set as predicate function to scan the entire row.

```
(defn get-row [data]
  (for [row data
        :when (some #{"a"} row)]
    row))
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better than the currently selected answer, this would work:

```
(filter #(= "a" (% 0)) data)
```

The reason for this is because for the top answer you are searching all the indexes of the sub-vectors for your query, **whereas you might only wantto look in the first index of each sub-vector** (in this case, search through each position 0 for "a", before returning the whole sub-vector if true)